# How to remove rule in moderncv banking style?

Tags: latex, xelatex

There is an example in the moderncv package where the are no rule for the Banking style. Here is the file [template_banking_red-norules](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_banking_red-norules.pdf). I would like to know how to remove the rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same folder there is a template.tex, open it and find the part in the preamble where it says

`% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}`

First change the theme from `casual` to `banking`; next add the style-option `norules`.

Your final preamble should therefore contain

`% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle[norules]{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}`

For further options and information about the style (and a way to manually manipulate it) have a look at **moderncvstylebanking.sty**, found online [here](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstylebanking.sty).